# AsyncSocket in java?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, asyncsocket

How can I implement an AsyncSocket in java (specificaly on android)?

Comment: you mean something like, http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ ?

Comment: @sbridges yes! I have used this library successfully in an iphone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do non blocking io in java without having 1 or more threads per socket, you have to use the java [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) libraries.  There are some wrappers around NIO that make it easier to use,  [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is a good example.

Comment: I'll look into it. Too bad there is no simple solution for it in java.

Comment: @Alex1987: It's a complex problem. You can't express it simply. NB NIO is not Async as conventionally understood, i.e. where the operation continues in parallel and you get a completion notification: it is non-blocking, meaning that only the part of the operation that can be completed without blocking, e.g. to/from the socket buffers, actually occurs. Not the same thing. IBM had an implementation of async sockets at one time but it was bound to Windows.